# How to specify order of required files in Angular CLI for Angular2?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-cli

I am building a SPA using Angular2. I am using **angular-cli *[version 1.0.0 Beta-14 with Webpack]*** with it for scaffolding, live development server, building the app, etc.

#### Problem:

I am using **Bootstrap** in my application for styling and layouts. Bootstrap **requires jQuery** for some of it's features to function properly. As a result, it becomes mandatory to load the jQuery script *before* the bootstrap files however I can't seem to find a way to do so in angular-cli

#### Question:

In angular-cli we list down all the required external/third-party files in the *angular-cli.json* file where all script files are in the *scripts* array and css files in the *styles* array. I am trying to find a way where I can tell my application to load the jQuery js files before bootstrap is loaded. I tried listing the jQuery entry before bootstrap entry but did not help. How can I achieve this in angular-cli?

**PS: As a work around approach, I have currently simply listed the files in index.html in the required order and this works however that is *not* the way I want it to be.**

Comment: Add it in your angular-cli in that order, i don't see any problem with that
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation

Comment: If you will check /node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-build-common.js, they have been mapped in same order.

var scripts = appConfig.scripts ? appConfig.scripts.map(function (script) { return path.resolve(appRoot, script); });

Comment: @user32, I have tried that already. It was not working unfortunately. Le me check again clearing the cache and everything

Comment: @user32, ah I got the problem. Apparently, when you port to webpack from earlier build, this problem occurs. I simply had to delete all the node modules and follow whatever you said. Please answer this question so that I can mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Yes, This might be the reason.

Comment: @user32, please answer this question as I said earlier so that I can mark this as correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127475/discussion-between-user32-and-ashhem).

Comment: I have the same problem with a clean installation. I don't know why, but jQuery is not getting loaded.